# Algorithm to solve recurrence number

Tags: algorithm

I need to find a "lucky number" which consists of same amount of 4 and 7 digits (ex. 4747, 4477, etc). Given an input n, i need to find the smallest "lucky number" that's bigger than, but closest to n (ex. if input is 6060, then the answer will be 7447). What is the best algorithm to solve this problem? Given that the input will be <= 10^100000. I thought about separate it into chars, and logically solve them, but there are cases which it's not easy to find out the answer. Could anyone tell me how to approach this problem?

Comment: Since you know the range, there is a finite number of possible solutions. You could just use a lookup table.

Comment: a lookup table for 10^10^5 values? On the other hand... this is ridiculous... how should the solution be presented? Good luck printing 10^10^5 digits.

Comment: Here is half the solution: if the number has n digits and n is odd, then the solution is (n+1)/2 4s followed by (n+1)/2 7s.

Comment: i figured it out when n is odd, the only problem remaining right now is when n is even. Thanks though

Comment: Go from most significant digit and check each digit, depending on its value put to Your output array 4 or 7, You will have to keep number of 4s and 7s of output table and also solve corner case ie. when most significant digit is greater than 7.

Comment: @maraca: You do realize that 10^100000 has only 100,001 digits, right? It's quite easy to hold that in memory and manipulate it.

Answer (score 1):

The below algorithm has worst-case linear time, which is optimal.

It's a bit complicated, though; it involves a lot of scanning one way and then the other way and then the first way again. There may be a simpler algorithm that is also optimal. (And a realistic implementation would add minor optimizations to improve the average case, and/or to improve worst-case performance by a constant factor.)

- **Step #1:** Handle the cases where the result will require more digits than the input.

  - **1a.** If *n* (the length of the input) is odd, then the desired result is the '444…44777…77' with length *n*+1. Populate the output-buffer with that result, then return.
  - **1b.** If the input is greater than the '777…77444…44' with length *n*, then the desired result is the '444…44777…77' with length *n*+2. Populate the output-buffer with that result, then return.
- **Step #2:** Copy the input into the output-buffer. (From here on out, we'll be operating directly on the output-buffer.)
- **Step #3:** Mutate the output-buffer to be the least integer consisting solely of 4s and 7s that is greater than or equal to its current value. (For example, if it's "4723", then we want "4744".) To do this, scan from left to right (most-significant-digit to least-significant-digit), seeking the first digit that is not 4 or 7. (If no such digit is found, proceed to step #4.) There are three cases, depending on the value of this digit:

  - *Case 0–3:* If this digit is less than 4, then change it, and each digit to the right of it, to a 4.
  - *Case 5–6:* If this digit is either 5 or 6, then change it to a 7, and change each digit to the right of it to a 4.
  - *Case 8–9:* If this digit is either 8 or 9, then scan leftward again, finding the first 4. (We know there must be one, because otherwise we would have exited in step #1.) Change that 4 to a 7, and change each digit to the right of that formerly-4 to a 4.
- **Step #4:** Mutate the output-buffer to be the least integer consisting of equal counts of 4s and 7s that is greater than or equal to its current value. (For example, if it's "4744", then we want "4747".)

  - **4a:** Count the 4s and 7s in the output-buffer.
  - **4b:** If there are more 7s than 4s, then compute how many 7s would need to be changed to 4s in order for them to be balanced. Call this *k*. Proceed from right to left until you have "encountered" *k*+1 7s, then continue leftward until you encounter a 4. (We know there must be one, because otherwise we would have exited in step #1.) Change that 4 to a 7; then change each digit to the right of that formerly-4 to a 4. Afterward, re-count the 4s and 7s in the output-buffer. (Note: after this sub-step, there may be more 4s than 7s. For example, if we had "4777", then we now have "7444". The next sub-step will take care of this.)
  - **4c:** If there are more 4s than 7s, then compute how many 7s would need to be changed to 4s in order for them to be balanced. Call this *k*. Proceed from right to left. As you come across 4s, change them to 7s, until you have changed *k* 4s to 7s.

Comment: thanks, that did it.